# UIImageView object starting in wrong location

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview, core-animation

To fully understand this problem some information needs to be given. My brother and I are developing a game for the iOS. The game has characters in it who walk (animated) from the right side of the screen to the left. These objects are created as a subclass of UIImageView. For example, we have a CharacterImageView that is created through its initializer during a timer on a view controller. So when the timer runs, we increase a variable by one. When the variable reaches a certain number it will create and add an object to the superview such as [[CharacterImageView alloc] init]; However, we use a custom initializer:

When we initialize this object we pass it multiple properties, one of them being the CGRect to set its frame. We create multiple instances of the same class during any given level. So the CharacterImageView might have 30+ objects initialized with one of six possible starting CGRects. These objects immediately create a timer in their initializer and start running it. The timer manages the animation, which is set up something like this:

```
- (void)characterTimerFired:(NSTimer *)newTimer
{
    // Get the presentationLayer coordinates
    CALayer *characterLayer = self.layer.presentationLayer;
    CGPoint currentPoint;
    currentPoint.x = characterLayer.position.x;
    currentPoint.y = characterLayer.position.y;

    // If there are no animation keys, begin a new animation
    if (!self.layer.animationKeys)
    {
        [CharacterImageView animationWithDuration:3.0
                                            delay:0.0
                                          options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                       animations:^{
            CABasicAnimation *characterWalking = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

            CGPoint newPoint;
            newPoint.x = currentPoint.x - 100;
            newPoint.y = currentPoint.y;

            [characterWalking setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:currentPoint];
            [characterWalking setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:newPoint];
            [characterWalking setDuration:3.0];

            [self setAnimationImages:walkingImageArray];
            [self setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
            [self setAnimationDuration:1.0];
            [self startAnimating];

            [[self layer] addAnimation:characterWalking forKey:@"position"];
            [CharacterImageView commitAnimations];
            [[self layer] setPosition:newPoint];
                                                    }
                                        completion:nil];
     }
```

Ok, so now that the basic information has been given, here's the problem. Every so often, the CharacterImageView won't start in it's proper location. Instead, it begins and finishes it's animation in the top left corner of the iDevice (landscape orientation). Any information would be greatly appreciated and if I need to be more detailed or present more code let me know.

The game is playable and out of 100 - 200 character creations this usually only occurs once. But it's still something that needs to be corrected as it will interfere with gameplay.

Comment: 1. `CALayer` does not have an `x` or `y` property (lines 6-7). Is that actually in your code or is it a mistake in the question? 2. I would debug this issue by to find where the position gets set incorrectly. add in an `NSLog` logging `currentPoint` (`NSStringFromCGPoint(currentPoint)`), and `newPoint` to see if and when their values appear incorrect. Add another log elsewhere wherever the layer coordinates may get changed to see what sets them to the incorrect values.

Comment: Two questions: Are you intentionally mixing UIView block animations and CAAnimations for some reason? Also, are you familiar with the difference between a CALayer's model layer and its presentation layer?

Comment: I fixed the issue in lines 6 & 7. Should have been based off of the position.

Comment: Aaron, what's wrong with mixing them? And yes, I'm familiar with the model and presentation layers to a certain extent. But if I'm doing something wrong by grabbing the presentationLayer position let me know.